# How to send contract using web3gl

Tags: contract-development, transactions, c#

I tried to send contract from web3gl to BUSD.
But I am not sure how to pass arguments and value.
Please give me some help.

```
// smart contract method to call
    string method = "transfer";
    // abi in json format

    string abi = "[{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"disregardProposeOwner\",\"outputs\":[],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"name\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"string\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"name\":\"_spender\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"name\":\"_value\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"approve\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"bool\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"assetProtectionRole\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"totalSupply\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"name\":\"_to\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"name\":\"_value\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"reward\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"bool\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"name\":\"_from\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"name\":\"_to\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"name\":\"_value\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"transferFrom\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"bool\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"initializeDomainSeparator\",\"outputs\":[],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"decimals\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint8\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"unpause\",\"outputs\":[],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"name\":\"_addr\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"unfreeze\",\"outputs\":[],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"claimOwnership\",\"outputs\":[],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"name\":\"_newSupplyController\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"setSupplyController\",\"outputs\":[],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"paused\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"bool\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[{\"name\":\"_addr\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"balanceOf\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"initialize\",\"outputs\":[],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"pause\",\"outputs\":[],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"name\":\"_newAssetProtectionRole\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"setAssetProtectionRole\",\"outputs\":[],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"name\":\"_addr\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"freeze\",\"outputs\":[],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"owner\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"symbol\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"string\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"name\":\"_to\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"name\":\"_value\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"transfer\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"bool\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"name\":\"_proposedOwner\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"proposeOwner\",\"outputs\":[],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"name\":\"_value\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"increaseSupply\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"success\",\"type\":\"bool\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"betaDelegateWhitelister\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"proposedOwner\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[{\"name\":\"_owner\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"name\":\"_spender\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"allowance\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"name\":\"_addr\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"wipeFrozenAddress\",\"outputs\":[],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"EIP712_DOMAIN_HASH\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"bytes32\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[{\"name\":\"_addr\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"isFrozen\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"bool\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"supplyController\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"reclaimBUSD\",\"outputs\":[],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"constructor\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":true,\"name\":\"from\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":true,\"name\":\"to\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":false,\"name\":\"value\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"Transfer\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":true,\"name\":\"owner\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":true,\"name\":\"spender\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":false,\"name\":\"value\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"Approval\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":true,\"name\":\"currentOwner\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":true,\"name\":\"proposedOwner\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"OwnershipTransferProposed\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":true,\"name\":\"oldProposedOwner\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"OwnershipTransferDisregarded\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":true,\"name\":\"oldOwner\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":true,\"name\":\"newOwner\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"OwnershipTransferred\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"Pause\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"Unpause\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":true,\"name\":\"addr\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"AddressFrozen\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":true,\"name\":\"addr\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"AddressUnfrozen\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":true,\"name\":\"addr\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"FrozenAddressWiped\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":true,\"name\":\"oldAssetProtectionRole\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":true,\"name\":\"newAssetProtectionRole\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"AssetProtectionRoleSet\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":true,\"name\":\"to\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":false,\"name\":\"value\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"SupplyIncreased\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":true,\"name\":\"from\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":false,\"name\":\"value\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"SupplyDecreased\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":true,\"name\":\"oldSupplyController\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":true,\"name\":\"newSupplyController\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"SupplyControllerSet\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":true,\"name\":\"from\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":true,\"name\":\"to\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":false,\"name\":\"value\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"indexed\":false,\"name\":\"seq\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"indexed\":false,\"name\":\"fee\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"BetaDelegatedTransfer\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":true,\"name\":\"oldWhitelister\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":true,\"name\":\"newWhitelister\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"BetaDelegateWhitelisterSet\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":true,\"name\":\"newDelegate\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"BetaDelegateWhitelisted\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":true,\"name\":\"oldDelegate\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"BetaDelegateUnwhitelisted\",\"type\":\"event\"}]";
    // address of contract
    string contract = "0x6F1583361c6Fe3f24E2371cAc3828A26a98F11a5";
    **// array of arguments for contract
    string args = "";
    // value in wei
    
    string value = "";**
    // gas limit OPTIONAL
    string gasLimit = "";
    // gas price OPTIONAL
    string gasPrice = "";
    // connects to user's browser wallet (metamask) to update contract state
    try {
        string response = await Web3GL.SendContract(method, abi, contract, args, value, gasLimit, gasPrice);
        Debug.Log(response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Debug.LogException(e, this);
    }
```

BUSDImplementation.sol

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public whenNotPaused returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0), "cannot transfer to address zero");
    require(!frozen[_to] && !frozen[msg.sender], "address frozen");
    require(_value <= balances[msg.sender], "insufficient funds");

    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
}
```

how to send arguments for "address _to" and "unit256 value"?